# When should each type of vertical bar (pipe) be used?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

There are many ways to type a pipe. You could use \$|\$ ($|$), \$\vert\$ ($\vert$), \$\mid\$ ($\mid$), or just a plain | (not surrounded by dollar signs). You could also use vmatrix to indicate matrix determinants.

I wanted to know when is it appropriate to use each type of pipe on Mathematics Stack Exchange. For example, pipes can be used in the following cases:

- To indicate that one integer is a factor (or divisor) of another (e.g. $2|4$)
- To indicate conditions in set notation (e.g. $Dom(\sqrt{x}) = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x \ge 0\}$)
- To indicate absolute value (e.g. $|-2019| = |2019| = 2019$)
- To indicate the cardinality of a set (e.g. $|\emptyset|=0$)
- To indicate the order of an element of a group (e.g. $\forall x \in K_4 ((x=e) \lor (|x|=2))$, where $K_4$ is the Klein four-group)
- To indicate the determinant of a square matrix (e.g. $\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 3\\5 & 7 \end{vmatrix}=-1$)

There is also of course the double pipe symbol ($||$), which is used for logical or in programming, concatenation, and parallel lines; and should not be confused with the number eleven.

Comment: Honestly, I think that this might be a better question for either the main site, or (even better) the [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) sister sister.  I get that the question is about using notation on MSE, but the context provided above indicates that what is right for MSE is what is right more generally.

Comment: Also it depends on, if you want it to scale or not. Sometimes left and right commands get involved.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar#Usage

Comment: On tex.se one finds for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498/mid-vertical-bar-vert-lvert-rvert-divides For such things it's not clear if it's identical for MathJax but likely it is. Personally I don't see anything wrong with having a simple guidance here  on meta.

Comment: I saw this on the sidebar and expected it to be about black, galvanized, PVC, and other pipe materials.

Comment: @Ross, and you expected to vote to close it as off-topic, I imagine.

Comment: Aside from the main question of which pipe to use, rather than `|-2|` for $|-2|$ you should use `|{-2}|` for $|{-2}|$, solving the spacing issue. (Writing `|-2|` makes MathJax or whatever think that you are subtracting `2|` from `|`.)

Comment: No mention of vector norm $\|\vec v\|$?

Answer (score 17):

Since you asked about some specific meanings when the vertical line appears:

- For divisibility, you use `\mid` (and `\nmid`) for "does not divide". For example, `$a\mid b$` $a\mid b$, `$4\mid8$` $4\mid8$, `$4\nmid7$` $4\nmid7$. The advantage over typing just `$4|8$` $4|8$ is that `\mid` yields extra spacing (but some authors prefer $4|8$).
- For conditions in set notation, use again `\mid`. (However, other symbols are also used for this purpose, not just vertical bar.)
- For absolute value, you can use simply `|`, for example, `$|x+2|+|x-2|=4$` $|x+2|+|x-2|=4$. Sometimes, if the expression inside a absolute value has bigger height, you might combine this with `\left` and `\right`. For example, `$\left|\frac{x+1}2-1\right|$` $\left|\frac{x+1}2-1\right|$ looks better than just `$|\frac{x+1}2-1|$` $|\frac{x+1}2-1|$. You can also use `\lvert` and `\rvert`. `$\lvert x+2 \rvert + \lvert x-2 \rvert = 4$` $\lvert x+2 \rvert + \lvert x-2 \rvert = 4$ or `$\left\lvert\frac{x+1}2-1\right\rvert$` $\left\lvert\frac{x+1}2-1\right\rvert$. You can treat the order of a group or the cardinality of a set in the same way.
- For determinants, you can use `vmatrix` environment. For example,
  $$\begin{vmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
    a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} 
  \end{vmatrix}$$
  is obtained using

  `$$\begin{vmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
    a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} 
  \end{vmatrix}$$`

Although MathJax is different from LaTeX, many things which can be used in LaTeX apply also in MathJax. So if you find some advice on math mode in LaTeX, it is reasonable to try them also here.

See also:

- The section on matrices in [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5023#5023).
- [Absolute Value Symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43008) on TeX Stack Exchange.
- [\mid, | (vertical bar), \vert, \lvert, \rvert, \divides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/498) on Tex Stack Exchange (this was already linked in [Jack's answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30586/when-should-each-type-of-pipe-be-used/30588#30588) and [quid's comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30586/when-should-each-type-of-pipe-be-used/30588#comment132454_30586)).
- [vertical bar for absolute value and conditional expectation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187162) on TeX Stack Exchange; [Absolute value size! (\lvert doesn't scale)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/277833) on TeX Stack Exchange
- [a ∣ b and a ∤ b in formulas](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116580) on TeX Stack Exchange
- [How to automatically resize the vertical bar in a set comprehension?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448) on TeX Stack Exchange.

Comment: This is a [community wiki](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/community-wiki/info) post, if somebody has further additions and improvements, feel free to edit them.

Comment: I don't like `\mid` for divides because of the extra space around it. I generaly use either `\vert` or `\divides`. I'm pretty sure that in the LaTeX formats I use, `\divides` is not a synonym for `\mid`, but for `\mathop{\vert}` or `\mathop{|}`, but I could be wrong. Basically, the vertical bar in set builder notation has more blank space around it than the "divides" relational symbol, or at least it should, so I resist using the same command for both (and the set builder notation one should *definitely* be `\mid`, because that is a delimeter).

Comment: For "divides" both the "little space" and "extra space" `\mid` are used in popular number theory textbooks so there does not seem to be any standard. In particular, it is wrong to call one the "correct spacing". That's merely a *personal opinion*.

Comment: Good thing the word “correct” doesn’t appear in my comment, and it starts with “I don’t like”, thus expressing my personal opinion. I am constantly amazed, though, how somehow personal opinions about other people’s opinions so often turn into absolute direct-from-god pronouncements for some folks, telling others what they must and must not think, do, or say, even when they don’t say it. On this and oh so many other topics past and present.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Well, an advantage of a CW post is that it is edited by the community - so if I originally got something wrong/incomplete, it can be edited by others. Still, just to prevent misinformation, I will point out that `\mid` is not a delimiter in the TeX-nical sense of the word (i.e., the construction with `\left\mid...\right\mid` does not work). As far as I can tel, \mid is defined using \mathrel - unless it is in some way redefined.

Comment: @MartinSleziak TeXnically, `\mid` is `\mathchar"326A`. That is class 3, i.e., a relation. So you're *mostly* right. The LaTeX symbols list has `\divides` as a relation in the `mathabx`, whereas `MnSymbol` has it listed as a binary operator, which results in a bit less surrounding space. (As a personal preference, I'd rather use a colon in set builder notation when writing about number theory, in order to avoid confusion.)

Comment: @Arturo (and readers). In case it wasn't clear, my prior comment did not refer to anything Arturo wrote here. Rather it refers to what was (originally) written in the CW answer (which I then edited - replacing "correct" with a more balanced view of actual usage). In fact  Arturo and I had recently [discussed such,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45750/why-is-working-in-mathbb-z-m-essentially-the-same-as-working-with-congru/45775#comment6797924_45775) and he reminded me that some authors do prefer the little-spaced version (which I confirmed by perusing some popular ENT textbooks).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Yes, in the TeX-nichal sense, `\mid` is a relational symbol; you need to use `\Bigm|` or `\middle|` for resizable delimeters. Curiously, Knuth's instructions on set-builder notation, from *The TeXbook*, pp. 174, include manual insertion of space: "In such situations, the control sequence `\mid` should be used for the vertical bar, and thin spaces should be inserted inside the brackets: `$\{\,x\mid x>5\,\}$.`"

Answer (score 5):

I believe the word "[pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar#Pipe)" is used more in computer science than in mathematics.

Unlike the strict syntax requirement in programming languages, *how* to type out this vertical bar in mathematical writing is mostly about typographical consideration. There are discussions regarding different commands in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/498/5590) at https://tex.stackexchange.com. Mathematically, it does not really matter.

Comment: Yes,I know the term "pipe" from using Unix long ago.  But nowadays mathematicians will not know that "pipe" means $\vert$.

Comment: As an R programmer, I expected "pipe" to mean %>%